# Android messanger app: user online / offline status

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am searching for 5 days how to check and show users-list online/offline in my android messenger app.I am new in android and i need suggestions.

I need to check and show users on/offline status :

[image: need to show the online/offline status here]

Comment: You should have to communicate with server guy otherwise it's i think imposibble.@B Dudhraj

Comment: *i went though different resources and can't find suitable for my app* ... then there is no such resource or your skills are to low to use one ... both possibilities exclude the answer

Comment: @Selvin ,i am totally new in android  and learning .i didn't get proper resources that can helpin my stage.

Comment: Only your server guy can help you to show Last seen and online/offline status

Comment: thnx for suggestion @DeepanshuHarbola

Answer (score 2):

I did it the following, not that it is the only way.

I used push notification system. When a user comes online, it sends a notification to the server, server checks its friends so that it knows whom to notify, then send another push to the correspondence devices. On reciever, instead of pop up, I just changed the view or etc...

I did that long ago with GCM for a company. Firebase is the new GCM. 
Not sure if it's the most helpful way but it works.

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/)

Comment: will look though it . @ibtehaz